# When to use what type of padding for convolution layers?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I know when we are using convolution layers in a neural net we usually use padding and mainly constant padding(e.g. zero padding). And there are different kinds of padding(e.g. symmetric, reflective, constant). But I am not sure what are the advantages and disadvantages of using different padding methods and when to use which one.

Comment: why was this downvoted? Please comment

Comment: I am not sure what has been down voted?

Comment: This question was negative until I voted it up. So far as I have found, optimal padding type is an open problem. That the only answer to this question so far has two links that only refer zero padding (only looked at  the tutorial+lecture notes, not the slides), and concludes that "You've just got to try them out". Zero padding works well because of properties of the convolution: it is effectively ignored, as if the convolution mask was only the size of the non-zero nodes. However, reflection padding these days is usually showing the best empirical results. If I learn more, I will answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am also still looking for answers and will update this if found any valuable answers.

Comment: @Ruby I have you one answer, but you havnt never told me, if you happy with that

Answer (score 3):

it really depends on the situation for what the neural network is intended. I would not tell it pros and cons. This time the world cannot put into a binary scheme.

I will give you some interesting links:

https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/

http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/lectures/

When you try to design a network, then start to think about what it should be designed for. Then, you try some things, it will be logical that , in case of convolutional networks, valid padding makes the image smaller and full padding makes the image bigger, but it uses, e.g zero padding, what adds 0 at the edges and could lead to veils... and so on... you must try a lot...

For pixelwise deep convolutional networks, people use `valid`, such as semantic segmentation. No/less "smear-effect". 
For object detection, people use `same`, only a bounding box is needed for the detected object.

HTH